# @ConditionalOnExpression if property is present

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have application.yml that has a property and it takes an array/list like this

```
tokens:
  token: 
    -  name: one
       site: chicago
  token:
    - name: two
      site: 'st. louis'
```

How do I use `@ConditionalOnExpression` such that just the presence of tokens in application.yml suffice?

I have tried `@ConditionalOnProperty("tokens")` and `@CondtionalOnProperty(prefix="tokens", value= {"token"}`. It does not work. Even the official doc suggests that with lists/arrays it won't work great.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It will be hard to maintain a property which is either present or absent. Programmer will have to go through the code to figure out what property to add for enabling. It would be better to have a second boolean property `tokenPresent`.

Comment: This is a very good advise. The trouble is, I am developing an application that will be added as a dependency in other projects. I don't want them to add unnecessary properties. You know what I mean?

Comment: Yeah. I did something like this few months back. Will add an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@Conditional(YourCondition.class)`

Quoating from [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Condition.html):

> A single condition that must be matched in order for a component to be
>   registered. Conditions are checked immediately before the
>   bean-definition is due to be registered and are free to veto
>   registration based on any criteria that can be determined at that
>   point.

#### Illustration:

```
@Conditional(MyCondition.class)
@Controller
public class Box{
   ...
}


public class MyCondition implements Condition{

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        Environment env = context.getEnvironment();
        return null == env.getProperty("tokens.token[0].name");
    }
}
```

Here, `en.getProperty` will return null in case of missing property.

Comment: In theory, `ConditionalOnProperty` would accomplish this.

Comment: Yeah, but here you can write your logic inside `MyCondition` class.

Comment: @AdityaGupta ty. i edited you answer a bit. If I ask for `env.getProperty("tokens")`, it always returns null. I have to give full property only then it actually returns a value instead of null.

Answer (score -1):

> @Faraz Durrani try this concept you will get...

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "tokens")
public class ServiceClass{

private String token;
   ...
}
```

Comment: No Kumar this is totally off. Sorry.

Comment: i done a sample on this and it's working for me ...better to try this....

Comment: yes I understand kumar. But my question is different. I think you misunderstood the question.